# drag div is creating more divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

Im trying to drag some .draggable divs and drop inside .droppable divs.

I have a working example (http://jsfiddle.net/amrezfq1/), but I have two issues:

first issue: When I drag a .draggable div and drop in .droppable div, the .draggable div dont stay where I drop, it always align at left of the div. (I think that its because of the append(), but dont know how to fix this)

second issue: I want to drag the divs that I put inside . droppable div, but When I do that, every time I drag a div inside .droppable, its created one more .draggable div.

Can you give a help put this working fine?

jQuery:

```
$(function () {
    $(".draggable").draggable({
        helper: 'clone',
        revert: 'invalid'
    });
    $(".droppable").droppable({
        drop:function(event,ui){
            var element=$(ui.draggable).clone();
            $(this).append(element);
            $(element).draggable();  
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. I added a class called `dragged` once the element is dropped. This avoids further invocation of drop event on the same element. Also extracted the offset() of the dropped element to set the position of it.

**UPDATE** : I've changed the code to extract the left margin using the difference of ui.offset.left and $(this).offset().left. Unfortunately, the top margin were not being extracted using the same logic. So i added my own calculations to determine it dynamically.

```
var itemsCount = 0;
var factor = 1.1;

$(function () {
    $(".draggable").draggable({
        helper: 'clone',
      revert: 'invalid'
    });
    $(".droppable").droppable({
        drop:function(event,ui){
             if(!$(ui.draggable).hasClass("dragged")){
                var element = $(ui.draggable).clone();                
                $(element).css({"left": ui.offset.left - $(this).offset().left});
                if(itemsCount > 0)
                {
                 var adjustedHeight = ($('.ui-draggable').css("height").replace("px","") * itemsCount * factor);   
                 $(element).css({"top" : ui.offset.top - ($(this).offset().top + adjustedHeight)}); 
                }
                $(element).addClass("dragged");
                $(element).draggable(); 
                $(this).append(element);
                itemsCount++;
             }
        }
    });
});
```

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/amrezfq1/3/

Comment: Thanks, your solution its working, just with one issue! The first .draggable div that is dragged to .droppable stays in the position that we drop, but if you drag a second .draggable div, that second drops always below the first .draggable div dropped in .droppable.

Comment: I've updated the solution and fiddle link. Please follow the section with UPDATE.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the position is off is because you're cloning the draggable, while the element you actually positioned is the helper. You can fix this by cloning the helper instead of the actual draggable.

To fix the duplicating issue, you can use the `accept` option of droppable to make sure the accepted draggable is not already inside droppable as shown below:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".draggable").draggable({
    helper: 'clone',
    revert: 'invalid'
  });
  $(".droppable").droppable({
    accept: ':not(.droppable > .draggable)',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      var element = ui.helper.clone();
      $(this).append(element);
      $(element).draggable({
        containment: this
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="draggable">draggabel</div>
<div class="droppable">droppable</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is working fine. But when you drag a div .draggable to .droppable, you can drag that div outside the yellow div, but I dont want that. I just want to move the divs inside the yellow div!

Comment: @ProjecT you can the [containment](https://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-containment) option. BTW, I didn't see any such point in original question. It is not encouraged to come up with new *requirements* once you get an answer in this site,. This is a `Q&A` site, if you want to do something further based on an answer, do some research, if you face problems afterwards, ask a different question...